# Laravel 8 - Target class [KontakteController] does not exist, but the ->namespace($this->namespace) is set

Tags: laravel

I get in my Vue Appliaction the error message:

"Target class [KontakteController] does not exist."

My KontakteController:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Kontakte;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class KontakteController extends BaseController
{
  public function fetchUsers()
  {
    $data = DB::table('Kontakte')->get();
    return $data;
  }
}
```

The api.php

```php
Route::get('fetchUsers', [KontakteController::class, 'fetchUsers']);
```

The web.php

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\KontakteController;

Route::get('/fetchUsers', [KontakteController::class,'fetchUsers']);
```

RouterServiceProvider.php:

```php
* @var string|null
     */
    // protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
        });
    }
```

And my Action:

```js
actions: {
    fetchUsers(ctx, queryParams) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios
          .get('/api/fetchUsers')
          .then(response => resolve(response))
          .catch(error => reject(error))
      }),

      console.log(response);
    },
```

I tried in the RouterServiceProvider.php with the protected $namespace and without this line.
But I always get the same error.

Comment: have you imported use App\Http\Controllers\KontakteController; in api.php

Comment: Post your relative file path and show your KontakteController class. Also uncomment the protected namespace atribute